# How Do I Pass `run_id` to a Message Create Call with OpenAI Assistants

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openai-api

I'm trying to add my current `run_id` to an outgoing messsage using the Assistants Beta on OpenAI's API in a Ruby on Rails 7 app, but I can't get the API it to recognize and accept the parameter.

When I put the run_id in the URI as a parameter, it generates the right URI (so I know the `run_id` is populating correctly:

```
  uri = URI.parse("https://api.openai.com/v1/threads/#{ self.support.thread_id }/messages?run_id=#{ self.class.last.run_id }")
```

But this still doesn't add the `run_id` to the response object of the new message being created.

I've also tried putting it in the body of the request:

```
  request.body = JSON.dump({
    "role" => "user",
    "content" => content,
    "run_id" => self.class.last.run_id
  })
```

...but this yields an error saying "1 validation error for Request\nbody -> run_id\n  extra fields not permitted (type=value_error.extra)".

Without a run ID for user messages, it's going to start new runs every time I send a message, things will get disjointed, and just all around chaos.

Has anyone tackled this issue successfully?

Answer (score 0):

> Without a run ID for user messages, it's going to start new runs every time I send a message, things will get disjointed, and just all around chaos.

This is not correct, you add as many messages as you like to a thread, and then you create a run on that thread, and the assistant will respond (ie. it will append its own messages to the thread).

You [can see more here](https://platform.openai.com/docs/assistants/how-it-works/objects)